# Rating movies through IMDB API

Tags: java, json, api, imdb

I would like to rate a movie from my Java code, but I don't know if it's possible to do it. I can download movie data and some things using JSON but I want to do this. Do you know any unofficial API or something to do it?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. You want to get information about the movie from IMDB but not the rating and then rate it yourself to send your rating back to IMDB?

Comment: They probably don't want automated programs affecting IMDB ratings

Comment: TMDb allows you to rate a movie programmatically, but I don't think IMDb does.

Comment: Yeah, I just want to rate it myself. Thanks anyway!

Comment: [imdb TOS](http://www.imdb.com/help/show_article?conditions) says *'Robots and Screen Scraping: You may not use robots ... on this site, except with our express written consent as noted below.'*

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, IMDB does not even have an official API.

But if you want to try to let users rate movies, there is an alternative. You can look into the [TMDB](http://www.themoviedb.org/) ([API here](http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/)).